# Why does an object's type refer to its interface? (Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software book)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, ooad, gang-of-four

Why does object's type refer to its interface? Why the term type is used here? In terms of C++ I am not able to understand it.

> Gamma, Erich. Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented
>   Software (Addison-Wesley Professional Computing Series) (Kindle
>   Locations 593-596). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.
>
> An object’s class defines how the object is implemented. The class
>   defines the object’s internal state and the implementation of its
>   operations. In contrast, an object’s type only refers to its
>   interface—the set of requests to which it can respond. An object can
>   have many types, and objects of different classes can have the same
>   type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does object's type refer to its interface? Why the term type is used here? In terms of C++ I am not able to understand it.

Objects in OOP are not very different from the real world. For example :

1. A `Car` *IS-A* `Vehicle`. By this definition, a `Car` has the ability to transport people/cargo from one place to another.
2. A `Car` is also a `Car`. By this definition, it has the ability to be *driven* using a steering wheel.

In the above example, a `Car` *IS-A* `Car` and a `Car` is also a `Vehicle` **because** it can be driven using a steering wheel to move cargo/people from one place to another. In other words, the type of an object in the real world is defined by the things you can do with it (vis-à-vis it's interface.)

If we use the above analogy in programming, `Car` is a subclass of `Vehicle` and code that has a `Car` object can use all functions from `Vehicle` as well as `Car`. This would mean that a `Car` *IS-A* `Vehicle` and a `Car`. In conclusion, the type of object is defined by its interface, i.e the set of operations it supports.

Answer (score 2):

An oversimplification...

1. Interface - a list of things that a class have and the things that it can do... a list of things that answer the "Whats"
2. Implementation - answers the question on "How" the "Whats" are accomplished.

Example:
   An interface IPackageMover that does 2 things and 2 classes (types) that actually implements the interface (and also do other things aside from the interface requires)

```
 // the interface
 public interface IPackageMover
 {
    string GetName();
    void public void MoveTo(Package package, string newAddress); 
 }

 // the "type" that has the implementation
 public class JoeThePackageMover : IPackageMover
 {
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Joe";
    }
    public void MoveTo(Package package, string newAddress)
    {
        PickUp(package);
        Drive(newAddress);
        DropOff(package);
    }
    public void PickUp(Package package)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    public void Drive(string newAddress)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    public void DropOff(Package package)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
 }

 // another "type" with the same interface
 public class PassTheBuckPackageMover : IPackageMover
 {
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "What do you want it to be?";
    }
    public void MoveTo(Package package, string newAddress)
    {
        var joe = new JoeThePackageMover();
        joe.MoveTo(package, newAddress);            
    }
    public void Chill()
    {
        //do stuff
    }

 }
```